# Meteor Reactivity seems to fail when Logging in

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a couple of utility function in my Meteor app that look like this:

```
Template.registerHelper('canManagePatients', () =>{
  const id = Meteor.userId();
  const aa = new AccountAccess(id);
  const val = aa.canManagePatients();
  return val;
});
```

My understanding is that Meteor.userId() is a recative data source and hence after login the state of these helpers should change.

Unfortunately however, it does not work like this and unless I reload, these options remain hidden after logging in. What am I missing?

This is how the AccountAccess class uses the userId:

```
constructor(userId){
  if (typeof userId !== "undefined"){
    this._userId = userId; 
  } else {
    this._userId = Meteor.userId();
  }
}

canManagePatients(){
  const practice = this.getCurrentPractice();
  if (!practice){
    return false;
  }
  const patientTagId = this._getPatientAdminTag()._id;
  const ownerTagId = this._getOwnerTag()._id;
  return practice.tags.some((obj)=>{
  return (obj === patientTagId || obj === ownerTagId);
  }); 
}
```

**Update**

This is an excerpt of what the template looks like. All works fine except for the four `{{#if }}` statements that only function correctly after a reload after logging in.

```
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {{#if currentUser}}
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{practice.name}}<br><b>Hello {{userName}}</b> (Not you? <b><u>Logout</u></b>)<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {{#if canManageUsers}}<li><a href="/manage-practice/users/">Manage Users</a></li>{{/if}}
            {{#if canManageForms}}<li><a href="/manage-practice/registration/">Manage Registration Settings</a></li>{{/if}}
            {{#if canManageForms}}<li><a href="/manage-practice/forms/">Manage Forms</a></li>{{/if}}
            {{#if canManagePatients}}<li><a href="/manage-practice/reports/">Reporting</a></li>{{/if}}

            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/widgets">Use compact UI</a></li>
            <li><a href="/dashboard">Use old UI</a></li>

            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a id="linkLogout">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        {{/if}}
      </ul>
      {{/if}}
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: Within a bootstrap dropdown I have rows like this ... `{{#if canManagePatients}}<li><a href="/manage-practice/patients/">Manage Users</a></li>{{/if}}` This works fine, except that after logging in I need to reload or all if statuments of this type hide the content.

Comment: Don't that dropdown require to be initialized with javascript?

Comment: Yes, but that is all happening and working nicely based on Bootstrap. My only issue is that the 4 if checks for the ability to manage certain featueres don't update correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of state initialization is inappropriate for a helper - it's better if your helpers are stateless since they can be called more often than you expect.

A better approach would be to use a [Tracker.autorun()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun) to setup a Session variable (or reactive var) and then have your helper refer to that:

```
Tracker.autorun(()=>{
  const aa = new AccountAccess(Meteor.userId());
  Session.set('canManagePatients',aa.canManagePatients());
});
```

Then your helper can just return the value of the Session variable:

```
Template.registerHelper('canManagePatients', () =>{
  return Session.get('canManagePatients');
});
```